# Make grip to fill panel using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have been trying to make my grid to fill the panel it is contained it but I am having issues. I want to two divs representing the grid in the panel body to fill the parent which is the panel body. Here is the markup below:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Welcome</div>

                <div class="panel-body" id="app">


                    <div class="row">


                        <div class=" col-lg-4 col-lg-4">

                            <ul class="list-group">
                                <li class="list-group-item" v-for="li in list">
                                </li>
                            </ul>


                        </div>


                        <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8 ">

                            <ul class="list-group">
                                <li class="list-group-item" v-for="li in list"> {{ li.body }}
                                </li>
                            </ul>

                        </div>


                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap columns automatically include left and right padding. You can remove this by adding a class to the columns as done so by Julien Melissas.

http://julienmelissas.com/no-gutter-column-trick-for-bootstrap/

```
.row.no-gutters {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}
.row.no-gutters > [class^="col-"],
.row.no-gutters > [class*=" col-"] {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

Adding these classes to your css file will allow you to add a no-gutters class to your rows.

Here's a Pen to show how it works.

http://codepen.io/mutualdesigns/pen/jAXRKm

If you want to remove the spaces to the left and right of the row inside of the panel, you'll need to override that element's padding in a similar fashion.